# Какой путь к файлам в OpenServer?

Tags: php, openserver, path

Впервые устанавливаю сайт на движке ModX на Openserver, так там много ссылок с указанием абсолютного пути к файлам. Как писать?
К примеру, на одом хостинге путь такой

```
/var/www/user/data/www/mysite.ru/
```

на другом такой

```
/home/user/domains/mysite.ru/
```

Какой путь указывать на локальном сервере OpenServer? И можно ли указать какую-то переменую, чтобы облегчить переезд с одного хостига на другой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам путь нужен для `require` тогда используйте константу `__DIR__` - вернет вам путь к выполняемому файлу. Если для чего то другого - найдите где установлен openserver там есть папка `domains` в которой находятся папки с вашими доменами

Comment: Я дописал в вопросе, спасибо, попробую.